# Notification of edits on questions you answered

Tags: feature-request, questions, editing

Is there a way to get notified when a question you have answered gets edited? Edits sometimes change the wording or meaning of the main question and a previously posted answer can seem badly worded or incorrect. Eg. if "Can i do X" is edited into "Am I forbidden to do X", an answer that highlighted "No" will be misleading, even if the reasoning below that is correct and clear.

Do we have something like this? If not, could we?

(Not sure if I should post this here or on some more general meta, help of that kind is also appreciated.)

Comment: this request on main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2322/311001

Answer (score 9):

We don't have an automated way for this to happen.

Ideally someone making such an edit (or spotting that such an edit has been made) would leave a comment on your answer suggesting it needs an update, or update it themselves if it's easy enough to do so and they feel so inclined.

Your specific example (an answer leading with simply “Yes” or “No”) is a learning scenario though: those types of answers break pretty easily with question edits. I recommend also summarising what is true such as by saying “No, (thing) is the case” or “No, you can't (thing)” or “Yes, you can do (thing)”; it's a more resilient response to changes in question phrasing.

Comment: Yeah, I usually see someone comment when the question is updated to flip the wording (e.g. initially, one question is asked in the title and the opposite question is asked in the body text) - or I'll comment myself. But yeah, "yes"/"no" one-word answers in general can easily get confusing.

Comment: This is a useful bit of guidance. I have a few "yes"/"no" answers out there that I shall now consider editing.